# Extra aliases in the url_alias table

Tags: 7, entities, path-aliases

In a module, entity_save is being called 2 times. Each time it's called, an extra alias row is being added to the url_alias table. I couldn't find any paths being saved in node_save.

Is this expected behavior?

The entity type I'm dealing with are nodes. [image: Extra Aliases]

Answer (score 0):

I found some code within the module that was placed as a work around for issue https://www.drupal.org/node/936222. Now that it's fixed, all is well.